# How to deploy entire React JS project files to Github for collaboration

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment

I'm currently working on a React App in visual studio code. However I need my friend to also work on the same project. I deployed it successfully to github but of course it only uploads the static build folder. How do I get the entire project across to my friend so he can work on it?

Comment: Have you  ... committed the source files to a repository? 
https://docs.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/importing-source-code-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Follow this instruction [link](https://docs.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/importing-source-code-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line) in their documentation on how to add an existing project to github. Or even simpler, VSCode has a built in "Publish to Github" command, use it. Make sure you don't ignore anything you don't want in the .gitignore file. You don't need to upload the static build folder though, ignore it in the .gitignore file. Your friend can build the project himself.
2. Open the Github repository settings and look for something called "Manage access". There you can see an option where you can invite a collaborator. That way your friend will have write access to the repo and can push change to the code.
3. Told him to clone the repo and accept the invite -> done.